# WSO2 LOGOUT ISSUE in SSO

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, single-logout

I'm using WSO2 IS to enable SSO for a service provider implemented in java. I want to perform logout and return to the home page of my SP but when I logout I get the following error:

> POST logout URI does not match with registred callback URI

Any suggestion how to make the right post logout URL. When debbugging the java application i found that the used redirect uri(callback uri) is: http://server:8080/openid/callback but the post logout uri value is: http://server:8080

Comment: Set the URI callback as `http://server:8080` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

When you are configuring the service provider in WSO2 IS, you can add multiple callback urls. Refer "**Callback Url**" section in [1]

In your case adding the callback as:

`regexp=(http://server:8080/openid/callback|http://server:8080)`

will fix your problem.
Since there is no separate section to configure postlogout url, you have to add it as a callback url.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on/#configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on